# Stopping a service after Intent -Android

Tags: android

In my android application, I have an activity called **A** .From **A**, I call a background service.In that services `onStartCommand` I will do some `AsyncTask` and Provided an Intent to move to another activity called B. Where I am stuck is,

**1.** How can I stop the service itself after calling the Intent?

**EDIT**: I tried calling `StopSelf();` but it not ending my service.

**2.** After reaching B the back button should not work. Currently if press backbutton I can still go to Activity A.

**My Intent**

```
Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(UserLoginValidationService.this,SplashScreen.class);                                            
                        dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);                       
                        stopSelf();
                        startActivity(dialogIntent);
```

**EDIT**: How to call `finishAffinity();` in service?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You cannot able to call finishAffinity from service.But u can call finishAffinity from activity.So my suggestions in implement a android view modle (android architecture components),live data.Watch that live in the each activity  based on that implement a observer in  the activities  in which u want to call finishaffinity/finish for that live data .Then you need to update that live data in th service . U can try like this

Comment: @SIVAKUMAR.J Bro can you give me some code samples? It will be great help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This could be the best way to do it.

1. Create an Intent Service.
2. Register a Local BroadcastReceiver in your A Activity from where you started 
   the Service.
3. Broadcast from your Intent Service and Receive it in you A Activity.
4. Do the needful in that BroadcastReceiver code.

**NOTE:** unregister BroadcastReceiver in A Activity onDestroy() method.

stopSelf() do stop the service but it could take little time. You can cross check it by putting log in onDestroy() Method of Service.

Answer (score 1):

**1. How can I stop the service itself after calling the Intent?**

You can stop service using `stopSelf()`.

**2. After reaching B the back button should not work. Currently if press backbutton I can still go to Activity A.**

If you want to close the application on back button press then you should open at Activity B clearing previous activity.

Comment: @ viram p :  If you want to close the application on back button press then you should open at Activity B using clear previous activity. -- for this finishAffinity() helps